# Making a bootable DVD

Tags: system-installation

I hate Windows 8.0.

I made a bootable USB drive and loaded Ubuntu with 8.0 onto my desktop computer and it is working fine.

I would like to load Ubuntu onto my laptop (Acer Aspire 5000). It will not boot from a USB stick.

I need a bootable DVD, but when I try to create one the web site gives me lots of malware. I reloaded XP to get rid of all the malware. I don't want to go back there if I don't have to.

I have tried to copy the files from the stick to a DVD using Windows and again using Ubuntu but the laptop would not boot from either DVD.

Is it possible to make a bootable DVD using my Ubuntu desktop that I can use to load Ubuntu onto my laptop?

Comment: Take a look at [Burning ISO How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! You must burn the DVD as a bootable ('El Torito' standard) disc from Windows (or some other OS); don't use UDF or packet-writing modes, don't leave the disc open for more material later. Also, don't use DVD-RW discs; only use DVD-R or DVD+R blanks.

No spamware-ridden website is needed to do that. Instead, here are two Open Source free spamfree Windows DVD/CD burner apps:  http://cdrtfe.sourceforge.net/ (English on the right side) and http://sourceforge.net/projects/infrarecorder/

And, as to the failure of the USB drive, well, perhaps USB is not enabled as a bootable device in your BIOS?